# Input output voltage problem in PIC32 starter kit & IO expansion board

Tags: pic, c, output, input

I have a `PIC32 Ethernet Starter kit` and `IO expansion board`. I have a made a simple input output program in which if `PINC2` is high then make `PINC1` high else low. I have a circuit which gives me a output voltage of 3.3v and I am applying this voltage as input to `PINC2`. But there is voltage problem at `PINC1`.

When `PINC2` is low, voltage at `PINC1` = 3.276v

When `PINC2` is high, voltage at `PINC1` = 2.8-2.9

My question is when voltage at `PINC2` is low, why voltage at `PINC1` is 3.276v, it should be 0volts. and when voltage at `PINC2` is high, why voltage at `PINC1` is 2.8-2.9v, it should be 3.276v. I am really confused at this. Please help

CODE:

```
int main() 
{

   TRISCbits.TRISC1=0; //output
   TRISCbits.TRISC2=1; //input
   while(1)
   {

       if(PORTCbits.RC2==1) 
       {

          PORTCbits.RC1=1; 
       }
       else if(PORTCbits.RC2==0)
       {

          PORTCbits.RC1=0; 
       }
   }
}
```

[Link](http://picpaste.com/Capture-BVp9sLBg.PNG) to circuit giving 3.3v output

Comment: what is the actual measured voltage at PINC2 when high and low? Are there any other connections to PINC2 other than opto-coupler output? Any other connections to PINC1 (pullup/pull down/ other circuitry)? Does the circuit work without opto? (Driving PINC2 from 3 .3 V supply directly?) Lastly, can you pls independently check that whether you are indeed driving the PINC1 high and low..Try toggling it directly in the code?

Comment: 1) actual measured voltage at PINC2 at low=0.75 & how can I measure it at high becuase I am applying 3.3v from couplers.
2)no connections at PINC2.
3)no connections at PINC1,but dont know about pull down/high as it is IO expansion board.When there is nothing it is 3.276v so maybe it is pull up.
4)yes it work without optocoupler, I made a program of switch and led and it works.
5) yes it is working

Comment: pls isolate the PinC2 and measure the high and low output voltage levels using a DMM. Also, pls post the high and low values when you connect PinC2 to opto.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to your TRISC configuration you might have to clear the ANSC register. This sets the port to didital mode and disables the analog functions of the pin. You did not mention the exact PIC model so I can't check on the exact functionality of RC1.
I came across this once when I configured a pin as UART input but the input did never read the digital Rx because it was configured as an analog pin.
I would furthermore check all other functions of RC2, and configure all those functions as disabled (e.g. ADC).